# Menu Boostrap com duas linhas

Tags: bootstrap-3

É possível criar um menu em Boostrap usando duas linhas? Tenho vários itens para colocar em um menu, estou diminuindo a fonte, tirei até o logo, mas não gostei do resultado. Gostaria de ter 2 linhas, para equilibrar o tamanho da fonte e poder usar o logo.

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Principal</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">O Fundador</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">O centro</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Reinserção</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Fotos</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Como encaminhar</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Equipe Técnica</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Prog. Terapêutica</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Outros Serviços</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Testemunhos</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Triagem</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Comunidade Evangélica</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:0.8em; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;" href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, como assim duas linhas? Você decidir quais items ficarão na linha superior e na inferior?

Comment: Exato, de forma manual, não automática, de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

Comment: Exemplo: http://imgur.com/a/q5F40

Comment: Não é possível colocar dentro de sub-categorias em um dropdown?

Comment: Bem que eu queria, mas o cliente está irredutível. Se não achar uma solução, vou ter que sugerir algo diferente.

Comment: No meu navbar nao quer dar de jeito nenhum, me manda o seu resultado porfavor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá amigo veja o codigo abaixo é basicamente o que você precisa, abraços.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navegacion-rb">
            <span class="sr-only">Visualizar / Ocultar Menu</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">LOGOTIPO</a>
        </div>
        <!-- INICIO DO MENU -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacion-rb">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ">
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Principal</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">O Fundador</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">O centro</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Fotos</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Como encaminhar</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Prog. Terapêutica</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ">
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Prog. Terapêutica</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Equipe Técnica</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Serviços</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Diversos</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Testemunhos</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Triagem</a></li>
              <li class="my-links"><a class="links" href="#">Comunidade Evangélica</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maravilha! Fico perfeito! Obrigado pelo suporte, @Rblima